# Partial fractions - alternative result

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions

I have the following fraction:

$$
\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}
$$

When I try to decompose it to partial fractions, I get:

$$
-\frac{1}{z-1} + \frac{2}{z-2}
$$

But the result in my book is:

$$
-\frac{z}{z-1} + \frac{z}{z-2}
$$

Both results are correct, but, how am I supposed to get the second one?

Comment: The book's result is non-standard, because one tries to get the degree of the numerator less than the degree of the denominator.

Comment: I need it in the second form to perform the inverse Z-transform on it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments that the result stated in the back of the book is somewhat non-standard.  The way that you can see that the two results are the same is by cleverly adding and subtracting 1.

\begin{align*}
\frac{-1}{z-1} + \frac{2}{z-2} &= \frac{-1}{z-1} -1 + \frac{2}{z-2} + 1 \\
&= \frac{-1}{z-1}-\frac{(z-1)}{z-1} + \frac{2}{z-2} + \frac{z-2}{z-2} \\
&= \frac{-z}{z-1} + \frac{z}{z-2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}=\frac{z(z-1)-z(z-2)}{(z-1)(z-2)}=...$